`--init-directory` is only working with runemacs.exe but not with emacsclientw.exe on Windows
A symbolic link on windows for emacsclientw.exe with the following flags:
C:\Users\XXX\bin\emacs-29.3\bin\emacsclientw.exe --init-directory "~/Dotfiles/emacs/.emacs.d/" -n -c -a ""
gives me an ERROR saying: "Try C:\Users\XXX\bin\emacs-29.3\bin\emacsclientw.exe --help for more information".
The shortcut works as expected when omitting the --init-directory-flag.
On top, a symbolic link to runemacs.exe with the same --init-directory-flag set, works as expected.
Does anybody has an idea how to fix this?
What I tried so far:

Putting the flag at different positions
Changing the ~ with the actual path C:/Users\gross20\AppData\Roaming
Changing the path separator from / to \\ and \


Does emacsclientw --help list --init-directory as an acceptable option? emacs and emacsclient are not the same program, so they don't take the same options. When you start emacs, you can specify --init-directory, but when you start emacsclient, it connects to an existing emacs: you cannot change the init directory of a running emacs, so it would be useless to have a --init-directory option in emacsclient.

emacsclient does not take an --init-directory option, as I explained in my comment. If you want emacsclient to start emacs using the -a option, you need to pass the proper command to it:
emacsclient -a "emacs --daemon --init-directory ~/Dotfiles/emacs/.emacs.d" -n -c

Note that the --init-directory option is given to emacs, not to emacsclient.
Edit: Windows only recognizes double quotes (") and the command must not have a trailing slash. Then it works.

Thanks, that is also what I tried after your comment but with no success. Starting it up by hand (i.e. runemacs.exe --daemon followed by a call to emacsclientw.exe -c -n) produces another ERROR that it can't find the socket (or alternate-editor)... So I'll have a llok where the server file is placed on windows... normally I do Linux as well, but not on my work machine

Ok, the first trick is not to start runemacs.exe with the daemon flag. Now it works as a three-step process: runemacs.exe with --init-directory-flag M-x server-start and then I can connect to the running server with emacsclientw.exe when I specify a server-file... so far so good. :-) I took inspiration from this answer: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/48029/30098

M-: (server--file-name) should return the path of the server file.

Another gotcha: the --init-directory within an --alternate-editor is a path relative to the "execute in" field ("Ausführen in"), whereas from the runemacs.exe it also takes absoulute paths... not sure if this is intentional or not. After a lot of fidelling this is finally the correct command:
%UserProfile%\bin\emacs-29.3\bin\emacsclientw.exe -a "%UserProfile%\bin\emacs-29.3\bin\runemacs.exe --init-directory 'AppData\Roaming\Dotfiles\emacs\.emacs.d\'" -n -c --server-file %APPDATA%\Dotfiles\emacs\.emacs.d\server\server

I would accept your answer now. However, the quotes need to be reversed: Inner double qoutes did not work, I have to use the double quotes for the -a-flag value and single quotes for the path. On top one could at the "peculiarity" concerning relative/absoulte paths to the --init-directory-flag within the -a-flag... could also be a Windows thing.

Oh no, I just noticed that it's not solved: the user-emacs-directory contains acutally the single quotes: "c:/Users/gross20/AppData/Roaming/'Dotfiles/emacs/.emacs.d/'/... but ommitting the quotes for the path I get the ERROR file name or argument required, there should be plenty arguments and passing a file name does not help either. I'm back to my manual three-step process...

I provided an edit to make your answer work for Windows too, hope that is fine.

Thanks! It would be helpful I think if you provided the command that finally worked: a working example is better than just a description IMO.

That's why I also edited your code example to work on Windows and Linux. (: Sorry, that I didn't made that clearer...

No, that's OK - thanks! As is, it should work on Linux, but I wonder if there will be problems in more complicated situations. We'll cross that bridge if/when we get to it though.
